# When do variables output properly in skeletons functions?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a skeleton-function to output expressions in a loop. Out of a loop I can do,

```
(define-skeleton test
    ""
    > "a")
```

When I evaluate this function it outputs "a" into the working buffer as desired. However, I'm having issues when inserting this into a loop. I now have,

```
(define-skeleton test
  "A test skeleton"
  (let ((i 1))
  (while (< i 5)
   >"a"
   (setq i (1+ i)))))
```

I would expect this to output "aaaaa". However, instead nothing is outputted into the working buffer in this case. What is happening when I insert the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `> somestring` skeleton dsl does not work inside lisp forms.
You can however concatenate the string inside a loop:

```
(define-skeleton barbaz
    ""
  ""
  (let ((s ""))
    (dotimes (i 5)
      (setq s (concat s "a")))
    s)
  )
```

My understanding is that code such as 
`> "a"`

only works at the first nesting level inside a skeleton.

**[EDIT]** Regarding your question

> What is happening when I insert the loop?

The return value of the `let` form (that is, the return value of the `while` form)is inserted. I do not know why it does not raise an error when evaluating `> "a"`, but the return value of a `while` form is `nil`, so nothing is inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but for some reason this also doesn't output "aaaaa" for me in the buffer that I'm working in (maybe it outputs it somewhere else I'm not sure). I also tried using >s instead of just s at the end of the function, but this still didn't output the string.

Comment: It's just a typo, replace ```ss``` with ```s```.

Comment: By the way, the `>` is used to control indentation. Take a look at the [skeleton language documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Skeleton-Language.html#Skeleton-Language): the skeleton is basically a list of strings, some special atoms (like `>`) and lisp forms. Lisp forms returning integers are outputted like characters, lisp forms returning strings are outputted as such, like the let form in my answer. Quoting (`'`) controls whether or not the form return value is outputted.

Comment: Great, thanks again. Quick addition is there any function instead of ">" that will print while still in the loop that you are familiar with?

Comment: As I said, `>` is not printing! It just tells the `skeleton-insert` function that what follows should be indented according to the major mode. 
The `insert` function is used to insert strings in a buffer, but if you are using it, you may as well not use `define-skeleton` and use a normal `defun` instead, like 


    (defun bar ()
      (interactive)
      (dotimes (i 5)
        (insert "a")))

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks so much for your help! I have no idea why I've been using skeletons for the last year.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that there's not much point using `define-skeleton` if you're going to need an `(insert` function within the skeleton. 
This is also a rather trivial example to be using `define-skeleton`.

That said, they are often easier to read than a `defun` and useful when you want to create a function that inserts text (and optionally, takes input).

For example you may wish to have a different character repeated a set no. of times... Below, `str` refers to the argument supplied with the function (usually a **str**ing) and `v1`, `v2` are the default names for local variables in a `skeleton`. Thus:

```
(define-skeleton s2 ""
  nil ; don't prompt for value of 'str'
  '(set 'v1 (make-string 5 (string-to-char str)))
  \n v1 \n \n)
```

Below, calling the function leads to a newline, the string, then leaves the cursor at the position indicated by the square brackets `[]`.

```
(s2 "a")
aaaaa
[]
```